# Rails Devise and user IP Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Currently using Devise 3.5.2 on top of Rails 4 with Devise's trackable turned on.

Through a bunch of micro-services, we have the client's IP address in a RequestStore. It works great except for when we want to save the IP address to the `user.current_sign_in_ip` attributes.

I tried to do:

```
def update_tracked_fields!(*)
  self.current_sign_in_ip = '10.0.0.1'
  super
end
```

But this does not give the desired behavior, in that upon login, the `last_sign_in_ip` gets the fixed `10.0.0.1` address.

What is the best way to override the IP address which Devise uses to store the IPs into?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the fragment of Devise `updated_tracked_fields` [method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb#L23-L25):

```
old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_ip, request.remote_ip
self.last_sign_in_ip     = old_current || new_current
self.current_sign_in_ip  = new_current
```

You can see that `current_sign_in_ip` is reassigned from `request.remote_ip`. So your code will have no effect.

One way to make it work is to try this code:

```
def update_tracked_fields!(request)
  update_tracked_fields(request)
  self.current_sign_in_ip = '10.0.0.1'
  save(validate: false)
end
```

Or even better:

```
def update_tracked_fields(request)
  super
  self.current_sign_in_ip = '10.0.0.1'
end
```

Comment: Ahh thank you - sorry for the simple question. I'm surprised trackable doesn't have some variable or method to override the IP with another one.